# pyautogui.click() giving errors with pathlib input

Tags: python, directory, pyautogui, pathlib

When I ran the following code:

```
import pyautogui as pya
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

imageFolder = PureWindowsPath(__file__).parent/'images'
print(imageFolder)
pya.PAUSE = 2
pya.click(imageFolder / "tiaoseban.png")
```

I got this error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'PureWindowsPath'`

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'PureWindowsPath'

Comment: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks Its because pyautogui doesn't click files it clicks locations based on the screen position (x,y coordinates). Your problem is with `pya.click()`

Comment: well, pyautogui can click an image, I can work with pya.click("tiaoseban.png") if I move the image to the same folder as the py file.  I only need to work with files in Image folder.

Comment: you will then need to convert imageFolder to a str() with `str(imageFolder)`